# Matlab fix echo in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I'm trying to fix an echo in an image.
The image is 256X256 pixels.
I used Inverse Filtering.

This is the code :

```
img=readImage('house');

lambda=0.001;
delta=zeros(256); 
delta(1,1)=1/2;
delta(1,20)=1/2;  % delta is The echo function used on real image
                  % I checked the axes and it is echoed 20 pixels to the right

G=fft2(img);   % Fourier Transform of echoed image

H=fft2(delta);  % Fourier transform of delta
Hs=conj(H);  %  H*

filter=Hs/(Hs*H+lambda)  
cleanim=filter*G;
cleanim=ifft2(cleanim);

imshow(cleanim,[]);
```

The filter matrix is a NaN matrix, why ? and what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not really sure about filtering. But the line: `filter=Hs/(Hs*H+lambda)` seems problematic to me cause the division there is matrix division with a singular matrix. Either you need to use pointwise `./` or use `diag(256)*lambda` (I guess it's the first).

Comment: At first, if by "echo" you mean a repeating pattern, then inverse filtering is not your solution as you may not now the frequency of the repetition. On the contrary typical Fourier-domain filtering works extremely well is such cases! Take the FFT of the noisy image and check where you get some high value. This high value is the frequency which corresponds to the pattern. Cancel this value (and possibly some values around it) and take in iFFT. Your image should be cleared of the noise.

Comment: I mean by echo, is having a double image of the same image, that the first's center is (0,0) and the second's is (0,20) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
filter=Hs./(Hs*H+lambda);
...
G=fftshift(fft2(img));
...
cleanim=filter.*G;
cleanim=ifft2(fftshift(cleanim));
imshow(real(cleanim),[]);
```

instead.

Comment: Tried that, now the filter matrix isn't NaN.
cleanim=ifft2(cleanim); => cleanim is mostly zeros, gives wrong image...
I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: Do you know that filter ? if yes, can you please tell me why all entries of every column of 'cleanim' are the same ?

Comment: see my update in answer, try that and observe what's going on. Thanks

Comment: I did that and examined the frequency, I changed all * to .* and saw that the frequency is similar to the 'img' frequency.
So mathematically it's not matrix multiplication.
A very good way to check what is going on !Thanks

Comment: Yes ! Done,it Works very nice, please if you can update or edit your answer so people with the same problem can see it.